# HTML PHP LARAVEL Multiple Text Input Fields With Same Value Considered As One Value

Tags: php, html, laravel

This is the code I'm using to fetch a few inputs at the same time from a few text boxes.
But when the text boxes have unique values then only I get an array of values in my PHP script. If the text boxes have same values then I only get one single value and not all the duplicate values. How should I fix this? Thanks Guys.

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
@for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/4 px-3 mb-2">
        <input
            class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-500 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
            id="inputs" name="inputs[]" type="text"
            placeholder="Text" value="000">
    </div>
@endfor
```

Comment: Can you show us more codes? You should be able to get the duplicate values.

Comment: @aceraven777 I tried a lot of times. But none worked out. It still doesn't allow duplicate values. Here's the original code of my project.
This is the blade html page : https://pastebin.com/tSW9pdXx
This is the PHP controller code : https://pastebin.com/spbU8AXT